# On my timeline, how can I immediately jump to an old post from several years ago and edit it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I would like to edit the privacy of several (perhaps all) of my timeline posts from before ~September 2013.  When viewing my own timeline, is there a way to somehow directly jump to those posts? Or do I have to manually scroll through all of my recent posts, waiting for the page to reload older posts as it scrolls?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I never figured out how to jump directly to a particular post.  [This outside post](https://www.reddit.com/r/facebook/comments/7z2536/weekly_questions_thread_february_21_2018_utc/) described how I could jump to a particular month and year.  But those instructions did not work for me.  As a workaround, I opened my "Activity Log" in Facebook, which allowed me to jump to a particular year.  But it only allowed me to jump to December 31 of that year.  So if I wanted to get to a post from May 2013, I had to jump to December 31 of 2013, then scroll down, page by page, through all activity of mine between December 31 and May.  Nevertheless, I was able to accomplish what I wanted.